# How to Force Stop multiple apps at once?

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean, force-stop

My HTC One X+ with Android 4.2.2 suffers a lag pretty often and I don't like that.
Sometimes I cannot even unlock the phone because screen doesn't come up.

I noticed that when I force stops all other apps (besides the one I am using) when phone lags, it runs smooth.
I have lot of apps installed so going to Apps then selecting the app and then force closing it takes a lot of time.

I am looking for a way where I can force stop multiple apps at once.

Comment: See if [Fast Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot) helps.   It closes all user processes and restarts/refreshes system-core process.

Comment: There are plenty of [app killers](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app%20killer&c=apps&hl=en) available on Google Play. You should just work through them to find one you like. The better solution is to really go through your applications and: 1. uninstall apps you really don't need; 2. make sure you are shutting down apps properly and completely after use (and not just using the "home" button"); 3. track down the heavy resource apps as it's probably only a few apps actually causing the issue.

Comment: @Manubhargav I am loving Fast Reboot. Whenever my phone lags or starts heating I tap on Fast Reboot app icon and it closes down all user processes and restart systems processes. Fast Reboot is the cleanest app I have seen so far. I am using it along with Phone Boost feature of Clean Master which automatically cleans up the RAM while phone is locked.

Comment: @devgr Glad to help. I'm going to post this as answer, for other people who have the same issue, for their reference.

Answer (score 1):

Greenify is also an app that can help you in this problem. It is one of the best task killer and battery saver app that I tried.

[Greenify's link on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

There is also [3c toolbox pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.at), a complete package with various tools. One tool is Task Manager that allows you to **kill** an app or **force-stop** an app. The latter does what you need.